# uint8_t Array Conversion to const char* in C

Tags: c, pointers, casting, function-call, function-declaration

Can you please help me convert this `uint8_t` array to a `const char*` in C?

```
uint8_t array = { 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, }
```

I am really having trouble passing it to a function which should be receiving a `const char*`.

Comment: Let me ask you this, what is the actual type of the `array` variable? And what are you expecting that type to be?

Comment: I have a uint8_t array[20] which I want to pass to this function.
int8_t qrcode_initText(QRCode *qrcode, uint8_t *modules, uint8_t version, uint8_t ecc, const char *data) as the data.

Answer (score 1):

For starters there are typos in this record

```
uint8_t array = { 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, }
```

You have to write at least like

```
uint8_t array[] = { 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, };
```

As for your question then just call the function like

```
func( ( const char * )array );
```

using explicit casting.

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void func( const char *s )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < 6; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", s[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );
}

int main( void ) 
{
    uint8_t array[] = { 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, };
    func( ( const char * )array );
}
```

The program output is

```
0 1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: I have this array uint8_t CountryID[] = { 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x01, }; that I want to pass to this function int8_t qrcode_initText(QRCode *qrcode, uint8_t *modules, uint8_t version, uint8_t ecc, const char *data)  as the data. I tried it and it's not working.

Comment: @JaneMalibiran What is unclear in my answer? I do not know what you are trying. The code I provided in my answer should work. If you have additional problems then ask a new question after closing this question.

Comment: Sorry. I think my question is unclear. I am saying that supposedly I have this.
 uint8_t array[]= {0x01,0x02,0x03,0x04,0x05,0x06,0x07,0x08,};

And I have this function that I want to pass that array as the const char *data
int8_t qrcode_initText(QRCode *qrcode, uint8_t *modules, uint8_t version, uint8_t ecc, const char *data) {}

Comment: @JaneMalibiran One more what is unclear in my answer?!

Comment: It is clear but is not working. Sorry to say.

Comment: @JaneMalibiran It is working. I provided a demonstration program. I advice you to close the question selecting the best answer because your question was answered and then to ask a new question with your problem with updates shown in my answer..